# How to run 'at' as a different user?

Tags: shell, environment-variables, sudo, su, at-job

I often need to run *at* jobs as a different user.  I've always done something like

```
$ echo "$PWD/batchToRun -parameters" | sudo su - otheruser -c "at now"
```

`batchToRun` is also scheduled to run via *otheruser*'s crontab.  This works out well until `batchToRun` starts depending on subtle side-effects of settings of environmental variables -- like **LANG** (*sort* anyone?) -- that are passed in from the environment of the user running `sudo`.

I typically don't want to log in as *otheruser*; it's a semi-privileged account and I would like a "paper trail" of its associated activity so that I can go back and see exactly what was done, by whom, when, etc.

Besides the obvious rewriting `batchToRun` to be independent of such settings, what's a good way to ensure  that the sudoer's environment doesn't contaminate the target environment?

Note: this is on FC7 (sudo version 1.6.8p12) and other old distros, so any shiny new features of `sudo`/`su`/`at` (notably, the ability to pass an argument with `-i` to `sudo`) are outside my grasp.

Update: it turns out that the `su - otheruser` is actually a sufficient firewall between the users and that my contamination is coming from something in the interactive startup sequence.  I still like the `env` edit capability, though.

Comment: If you're using both `sudo` and `su` you're probably doing something wrong. Try just `sudo -u otheruser at now`.

Comment: @OrangeDog note the `-` (and reference to FC7).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could strip the environment before you run `at`:

```
echo "command ..." | env - PATH="$PATH" sudo su - otheruser -c "at now"
```

You can also arrange for `sudo` to do this for you by setting the `env_reset` option.  For example, you could give your user access to run the `at` command as otheruser directly (rather than `sudo` to root and then to the other user) and then set env_reset with a `Defaults` command for that user or that command (see the sudoers man page).

But the above is probably the easiest solution without changing how you're generally doing things today.

Comment: Nice. And all these years, I thought "env" was only useful for printing out your environment.

Answer (score 0):

Any "contamination" of `otheruser`'s environment should be limited to the `at` command's environment. When it actually comes time to run `batchToRun`, it will be run by `otheruser` using its typical default environment. That is, only `at now` is run in the shell spawned by the `su sudo` command.

Comment: The behavior I see is consistent with that described on the "at" man page: The working directory, the environment (except for the variables TERM, DISPLAY and _) and  the umask  are  retained  from  the time of invocation.

Comment: Maybe you're suggesting that "su - otheruser" should be a clean break?  Now that I go back and examine things more closely, I find that's true -the source of environmental contamination seems to be something more insidious.